# Are maximal Ideals in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt 2]$ equal when their quotient rings are isomorphic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals, quotient-group

Let $R = \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt 2]$ and $M_1,M_2 \subset R$ be maximal ideals.

Prove or disprove: If $R/M_1$ isomorphic to $R/M_2$ then $M_1=M_2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Hint:* Consider $M_1 = (3 - \sqrt{2})$ and $M_2=(3 + \sqrt{2})$.

Comment: And, more generally, look at any rational prime that splits in $\Bbb Z[\sqrt2\,]$